# How to compress Base64/Binary image in Angular6?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I used `Ngx-Webcam` for capture image from camera. I want to get both high quality and low quality image from camera

This library return to me Base64 image. It have an option to reduce size `imageQuality` but I can't use because I need high both quality image and low quality image

```
let data = webcamImage.imageAsBase64;
const raw = window.atob(data);

const rawLength = raw.length;
const unit8array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
  unit8array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

I try to apply https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-conversion for our problem,

```
let data = webcamImage.imageAsBase64;
const raw = window.atob(data);
let contentType = raw.split(';')[0];

const rawLength = raw.length;
const unit8array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
  unit8array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}

let blob = new Blob([unit8array], {type: contentType});
imageProcess.compress(blob, 0.4);
```

But it was not work. I want to find another solution for compress image

Comment: The error mesage is pointing into the direction of something async not working out as expected (most likely some URL having an unexpected format). But the code you are showing doesn't have any async handling. Also the Error message is talking about a function called `dataURLtoImage` which is not present in your code example. Please try to give more context on the error message.

Comment: This is only 1 solution I tried. But my question is how to compress Base64/Binary Image.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, I was just pointing out that the error message might be unrelated to your question, or if you get rid of that error message your code might already do what you expect it to do.

Comment: What does “it was not work” mean? Did it not compress as much as you wanted? Did it produce a broken image? Did it throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to compress image with canvas

```
compress(webcamImage: WebcamImage, quality: number): Observable<string> {
  let _canvas = this.canvas;
  let width = webcamImage.width;
  let height = webcamImage.height;

  _canvas.width = width;
  _canvas.height = height;

  // paint snapshot image to canvas
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl;
  return Observable.create(observe => {
    (img.onload = () => {
      const context2d = _canvas.getContext('2d');
      context2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
      // read canvas content as image
      const mimeType: string = webcamImage.mineType;
      const dataUrl: string = _canvas.toDataURL(mimeType, quality);
      observe.next(dataUrl);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The base64 image was most likely already compressed (jpeg) before it was encoded in base64. You can't further compress such data.

If you need both high and low quality of the image, you should request a high quality (preferrably raw pixels) image from the webcam and transform it into jpeg images with different compression parameters.

If the camera only returns jpeg data, you need to decompress before recompressing with different parameters, which is possible but will consume more time and result in worse quality.

Ngx-webcam is probably a little limiting for this requirement, it might be necessary to look at its code and extend it somewhat to return captured images at different quality levels. There's a `captureImageData` flag that can be used to retrieve raw image data, but the documentation is a bit thin on how to work with that.

Comment: could you please share with me which lib use for `decompress before recompressing with different parameters`?

Comment: @khacsinhcs Sorry, that was just a general idea, I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript libraries. The image-conversion library that you already tried to use probably has everything you need.